# How to do back to footnote for different anchor elements using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, footnotes

I am having three different anchor links with unique ID, I wanted to make footnote to some other links on the same page.But I am facing issue with **Back to Footnote** is same for all the three anchor links.

```
<sup><a href="#one">One&nbsp;&Dagger;</a></sup><br/>
<sup><a href="#two">Two&nbsp;&Dagger;</a></sup><br/>
<sup><a href="#three">Three&nbsp;&Dagger;</a></sup>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
  <a href="#" id="one">&#x21B5;Back to footnote</a>
```

How do I make back to footnote reference to above anchors like "one", "two", "three" respectively.

Any help would be appreciated...thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want the links to go down to the "Back to footnote" link, then you want that "Back to footnote" link to go back to the link you've clicked on. If I'm wrong on the interpretation of your question, do comment and I'll adjust.

Basically, I've added an event listener to each links where when you click it changes the "Back to footnote" href to the correct anchor:

```js
var $anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('anchor');
var $footnote = document.getElementById('footnote');

for (var i = 0; i < $anchors.length; i++) {
  var $anchor = $anchors[i];
  
  $anchor.addEventListener('click', function () {
    $footnote.href = '#' + this.id;
  });
}
```

```html
<sup><a id="one" class="anchor" href="#footnote">One&nbsp;&Dagger;</a></sup>
<br><br><br>
<sup><a id="two" class="anchor" href="#footnote">Two&nbsp;&Dagger;</a></sup>
<br><br><br>
<sup><a id="three" class="anchor" href="#footnote">Three&nbsp;&Dagger;</a></sup>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="#" id="footnote">&#x21B5;Back to footnote</a>
```

jQuery

```js
$('.anchor').click(function() {
  $('#footnote').attr('href', '#' + this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<sup><a id="one" class="anchor" href="#footnote">One&nbsp;&Dagger;</a></sup>
<br><br><br>
<sup><a id="two" class="anchor" href="#footnote">Two&nbsp;&Dagger;</a></sup>
<br><br><br>
<sup><a id="three" class="anchor" href="#footnote">Three&nbsp;&Dagger;</a></sup>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<a href="#" id="footnote">&#x21B5;Back to footnote</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help...One more thing, if I have a back to footnote in separate anchor,den how we can reference back to already clicked anchor.

Comment: @Maniram I don't quite get what you mean, but I feel like my code should still work. Just try to change the anchor links, everything should work?

Comment: If am trying to convert this code to jquery, its not working as expected...

Comment: @Maniram I've added a jQuery version for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Nelson Yeung